# How can I use single transaction with multiple datasources with jdbcTemplate in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I need to rollback first statement if is there any error while executing second update statement in different database.
    I don't want to use EntityManager because I am already used JdbcTemplate in all other code. 
    If I use @Transactional with qualifier it works perfectly but I want @Transactional should work for both database.

**My code snippet is as follows:**

```
**DatasourceConfig.xml**
//Datasource for **DB2** database
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfigLmsDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
  scope="singleton" primary="true">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean> 

//Datasource for **Mysql** Database database
<bean id="dataSource1" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfigLmsDataSource1" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager1"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
  scope="singleton" primary="true">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
</bean>


//Inside service class
**MyService.java**

@Autowired("jdbcTemplate")
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired("jdbcTemplate1")
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1;

@Transactional
public void modifyDB()
{
    jdbcTemplate.update("Update query for table in DB2 database");
    jdbcTemplate1.update("Update query for table in MySql database");
}
```

Comment: Have you got the solution for this ?

Comment: Please check following link: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-jta-multiple-resource-transactions-in-tomcat-with-atomikos-example.html

Comment: in above link check applicationContext.xml section

Answer (score 0):

You need a global transaction manager . You can use Spring's JtaTransactionManager

Here is tutorial that shows it:

http://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/

Comment: That post not explained how can I configure multiple datasource's and multiple jdbctemplate's properly. If you have any other link with full example will help me lot. Thanks..